# How to animate a soft object while it is squashed on the floor?

Tags: animation

I need to animate a rotating soft object while it is squashed on the floor following the wavy shape of the floor.

Like in this video
https://youtu.be/cUsXyimUw6o?t=69 from 1:09 to 1:17

How I can do this?
Shape keys?
Physics?

Thanks

Comment: you could look up how a Lattice works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a ***Lattice*** modifier to squish the object:

[image]

Create a lattice, scale it in *Object* mode so that it contains your cylinder, subdivide it in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Resolution*, give it 2 shapekeys. Give your cylinder a *Lattice* modifier with the lattice as *Object*. Select the empty, select its second shapekey and deform it *Edit* mode, the cylinder should deform as well. Back in *Object* mode, put the shapekey value at 1. Animate the cylinder.

Comment: I solved half of the problem.
Now I don't know how to avoid squashing of the rigid plates object attached under my soft mesh (which is affected by the lattice distortion). These rigid objects should remain solid, the lattice modifier should not affect this rigid objects. Rigid objects should only be rotated following the movement of the soft object. How I can do it?